# Change the background color of search box and entry box in a datatable

Tags: r, dt

I would like to change the background color of the 'number of entries' and 'search box' at the top of the data table from white to -lets say- gray. Is this possible?

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "$('#DataTables_Table_0_length select').css('background-color', 'orange');",
  "$('#DataTables_Table_0_filter input').css('background-color', 'yellow');"
)

datatable(iris, callback = JS(callback))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `callback` argument:

Write JavaScript to select the HTML elements and change their CSS.

For example, I modified the background color using codes below. You can use similar approach to change the CSS of the search box.

```r
DT::datatable(iris,elementId = "thistable",
              callback = DT::JS("$('#thistable div[role=\"status\"]').css('background-color','red')"))
```

[image]